# gitignore - игнорирование и включение подкаталогов

Tags: git, gitignore

Допустим есть 2-уровневая вложенность каталогов

```
a1{1..10}/a{1..10}/{test},
b1...,
...
w...
```

Как мне исключить a1,a2,a3,a4, но оставить a{1..4}/a1/{test}?

Пример:

```
mkdir -p a{1..10}/a{1..10}

cat .gitignore
```

> ```
> !a2/test
>
> a1/a2
> a2
>
> !a1/a2/test
> ```

```
touch {a1,a2,a1/a2}/test


git status a2/test a1/a2/test
```

> ```
> На ветке master
>
> Начальный коммит
>
> нечего коммитить (создайте/скопируйте файлы, затем запустите «git add», чтобы отслеживать их)
> ```

Т.е. так это не работает.
Получается мне нужно описывать в .gitignore такую структуру для каждого файла:

```
cat .gitignore
```

> ```
> !a1/
> a1/*
> !a1/a1
> a1/a1/*
> !a1/a1/test
> ```

А если >5 уровней вложенности? 
Можно ли сделать это проще?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если в этих директориях `test` у вас какой-то постоянный набор файлов, то вы можете их подобавлять через `--force` один раз.

```
git add --force a{1..4}/a{1..4}/test
```

Теперь гит будет отслеживать все файлы, которые уже были в этих директориях, вопреки общему `.gitignore`. На новые файлы это не сработает, но можно снова подобавлять форсированно.

Comment: Рабочий вариант только в force, если там 5 уровней вложенности и нужно заигнорить a1, оставить a1/a2/a3/a4/a{1..4}/test, с множественными .gitignore будет так же "удобно"

Comment: @tannerman а про вложенные вообще уберу тогда